# How to start a react app that uses craco module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, craco

I forked a repo from github and I've been trying to start the application but I've been having errors. I've gotten past most of them(by installing packages and correcting typo errors), but I'm stuck with this error.

````
> dashboard@0.1.0 start /root/Projects/crazed-master/crazed-master
> craco start

(node:272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Projects/crazed-master/crazed-master/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/jit/corePlugins.js:242:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Projects/crazed-master/crazed-master/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/jit/lib/setupContextUtils.js:36:43)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
(node:272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:272) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Comment: My node version is: v16.11.1

Comment: I would suggest to start a new craco project. Then trabsfer the code from the forked project carefully one-by-one. (folders, files)